# Can not get one value from database

Tags: php

Can anyone here show me why i can not get one value from my database??
I did the same thing with other field but in the value $mieuta i can not get it.
my code is

```
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $tennsx = $_POST["tennsx"];
    $diachi = $_POST["diachi"];
    $sdt = $_POST["sdt"];
    $mieuta = $_POST["mieuta"];
    if ($tennsx=="" || $diachi=="" || $sdt =="" || $mieuta =="") {
    echo '<h4 align=center style="color: red;">Vui lòng nhập đầy đủ thông tin</h4>';
    }else{
    $sql = "UPDATE nhasx 
    set tennsx = '$tennsx', 
        diachi = '$diachi', 
        sdt = '$sdt', 
        mieuta =  '$mieuta' 
    where id = $id";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    //tiến hành lưu tên đăng nhập vào session để tiện xử lý sau này
    // Thực thi hành động sau khi lưu thông tin vào session
    // ở đây mình tiến hành chuyển hướng trang web tới một trang gọi là index.php
    header('Location:manu_management.php');
}
```

}

```
$id = "";
$tennsx = "";
$diachi = "";
$sdt = "";
$mieuta = "";
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    //thực hiện việc lấy thông tin nhasx
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $sql = "SELECT * from nhasx where id = $id";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ( $data = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
        $tennsx = $data["tennsx"];
        $diachi = $data["diachi"];
        $sdt = $data["sdt"];
        $mieuta = $data["mieuta"];
    }
}
```

i can see the value of $tennsx, $diachi and $sdt while the value $mieuta does not show up. please help

Comment: Did you check the database, if the value is updated there?

Comment: yep, if i update it, the value will be updated but it doesnt show the value when i wanna see like other value  :(

Comment: What does `print var_export($data,TRUE);` show?